# show Cortex-M4 SWO log with openocd

Tags: arm, cortex-m, openocd

I'm using ubuntu, openocd and stlink to develop stm32f407-discovery,
I'm learning to use ITM module through SWO pin to get log from chip. Finally, I found that openocd command

```
tpiu config internal /tmp/swo.out uart off 168000000
```

It's perfect to get log from the temporary file, but is there anyway to show log on openocd console directly, like semihosting log. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Actually you where very close to achieve the desirable outcome .
First thing first you don't have to specify an output stream ,the default is a named pipe that is  exposed on openocd's console .What I  mean is you could simply change:

```
tpiu config internal /tmp/swo.out uart off 168000000
```

with:

```
tpiu config internal - uart off 168000000
```

Although the problem that occurs then is that you need a parser to read the swo raw bytes ,fortunately there is this quite unknown but very useful repository that do just that with a single python script:
[swo_parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50075076/show-cortex-m4-swo-log-with-openocd/60772130#60772130)

So to sum up my configurations when I was debugging an f1 from a jtag (because the uart was occupied for other purposes) was:

1. Open two terminals
2. At the first terminal run`openocd -f debug.cfg`
3. At the second terminal run `python3 swo_parser.py`

debug.cfg contains just :

```
source [find interface/stlink-v2.cfg]
source [find target/stm32f1x.cfg]
init
tpiu config internal - uart off 72000000
itm ports on
```

also I forgot to mention you have to make one _write function like this
[ITM_SEND_CHAR definition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50075076/show-cortex-m4-swo-log-with-openocd/60772130#60772130)

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work using [Orbuculum](https://github.com/orbcode/orbuculum) as a helper program.

To get the output visible in same terminal as GDB, and to easily start everything at the same time, I start GDB like this:

```
arm-none-eabi-gdb \
       -iex 'target extended | openocd -f interface/stlink.cfg -f target/stm32f3x.cfg -c "gdb_port pipe"' \
       -iex 'mon halt' \
       -iex 'mon tpiu config internal swo.log uart false 2000000' \
       -iex 'shell bash -m -c "orbuculum -f swo.log &"' \
       -iex 'shell bash -m -c "orbcat -c 0,%c &"' \
       firmware.elf
```

The `-iex` parameter tells gdb to immediately execute a command when starting. Here is what the commands do:

1. `target extended ...` starts openocd and uses a pipe to communicate between it and gdb.
2. `mon halt` tells OpenOCD to stop any executing program.
3. `mon tpiu ...` configures OpenOCD to receive the trace output and to write it to `swo.log` file.
4. `shell bash -m "orbuculum ...` starts the Orbuculum server and tells it to read from `swo.log`. The `&` makes it run on the background, while `bash -m` runs it in separate process group so that `ctrl-c` within GDB doesn't accidentally stop it.
5. `shell bash -m "orbcat ...` starts Orbuculum tool to read any output from ITM port 0 and write that as characters to the terminal.

And here is what it looks like:

```
GNU gdb (GNU Tools for Arm Embedded Processors 8-2018-q4-major) 8.2.50.20181213-git
....
Reading symbols from firmware.elf...
(gdb) run
The program being debugged has been started already.
Start it from the beginning? (y or n) y
Starting program: firmware.elf 
target halted due to debug-request, current mode: Thread 
xPSR: 0x01000000 pc: 0x0800011c msp: 0x10001000
Boot
ADC ch 1 val -100
ADC ch 3 val 0
ADC ch 4 val 3
ADC ch 1 val 4091
.....
```

There are also other useful tools in the Orbuculum suite. For example `orbtop -e firmware.elf` shows the places where execution time is being spent.

Comment: You can even bypass `orbuculum` by serving the trace data on a port (use `:3443` instead of swo.log). This way, `orbcat` receives the trace data directly from OpenOCD.

Answer (score 0):

After searching for a few days, i've found nothing about openocd printing directly in a console.

What you can do is redirect it to a UART (requiring more hardware to setup) and use another program(like st link utility) to see the output, but it's way easier to just do a "cat /tmp/swo.out" in your terminal.